# Php md5 hash string plus foreach

Tags: php, hash

I have seen a tutorial for api md5 generate. The tutorial is like this.

```
String (API Method GET)
'key' // This is username
'secretkey' // This is appsecretkey
'dateline' // This is Timestamp
```

Tutorial as below:

```
<?php
    $secretkey = '';
    ksort($param); // $param is the string
    $params = '';
    foreach($param as $k => $v) {
        $params .= '&'.$k.'='.rawurlencode($v);
    }
    $md5hash = md5(substr($params, 1).$secretkey);
?>
```

so if
`$key = 'uusaaa';`, `$secretket = 'KFADG123123';`, `$dateline = '1468200841';`

so what will inside the `$md5hash` ?

I try something like `$md5hash = md5(&key=uusaaa&dateline=1468200841KFADG123123);` and the MD5 = `d3ad3a13db0f46473be677c1bb2ff237`

But the api side return error. so is it my `$param` wrong? actually what will the `$md5hash` look like?

Comment: How does the API server generate the MD5 hashes? I would imagine it is `md5($key . $secretkey . $dateline)`

Comment: I don't know how the API server generate the MD5, they just give us an tutorial to generate the MD5 
`<?php
    $secretkey = '';
    ksort($param); // $param is the string
    $params = '';
    foreach($param as $k => $v) {
        $params .= '&'.$k.'='.rawurlencode($v);
    }
    $md5hash = md5(substr($params, 1).$secretkey);
?>`

Comment: which API? wheres the documentation? (8865eb5ce2e8f570964ada5d4357e7db)